Problem with sorting categories in front end - ACF (Wordpress) custom post type
I have a problem sorting this content, I have no idea how to solve it. I use the ACF plugin in Wordpress, I want to display a list of categories alphabetically in the created post-type, but randomly refreshing the page sometimes changes their order. I'm a beginner in php, can anyone help?
this is source code
<?php
        $post_type = 'darmowy-sennik';
        $taxonomy = 'kategoria-sennik';

        $terms = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'hide_empty' => false,
        ));

        if (!empty($terms) && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link($term) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        } ?>

I try add
 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC',
And this also not help there

Related: get_terms() orderby name is not working - wordpress and Wordpress order taxonomies alphabetically

You can also sort items in php.
